# How to put all my elements in line horizontally and Should be Responsive using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code and it is putting the elements in vertical order one below other. I've tried using Grid system also but its failing when I use it in small screens.

And I've used the margins and padding to give spacing and that spacing is not responsive . How to do it?

Please help me the right code to put all elements in one line at and to be responsive to all screens;

Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="DockedPlayer" style=" background-color:#3F51B5;color:white; height:100px; margin-top:20px;">

            <img class="img-responsive" src="bhr2.png" width="80" height="80" style="margin-top:10px;">
            <text style="padding-left:15px;"> Mirchi Mirchi  </text>
            <img src="bakward.png" width="30" height="30" style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:150px; ">
            <img src="play.png" width="30" height="30" style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:50px; ">
            <img src="forward.png" width="30" height="30" style="margin-top:15px; margin-left:50px; ">

        </div>
```

CSS Related to it is:

```
#DockedPlayer{
           position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%; 

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `inline-block` display property to get them all in a line:

```
#DockedPlayer img,#DockedPlayer text{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

To make this responsive you may use CSS `media-queries` (Add these at the end of your `CSS` file):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    #DockedPlayer img,#DockedPlayer text{
         width: 100%;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 900px){
    #DockedPlayer img,#DockedPlayer text{
         width: 48%;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
    }
}
```

Making a design responsive, is a tricky thing, and the above is just a start point for that.

Comment: Ok thank you @Trix but it's not responsive. Coming in a line but It should adapt to all screens right. I've used padding and margins is it a problem.

Comment: Waiting... Thank you

Comment: If u need width 50%, then you should really put them inline in ur markup, instead of putting them line by line

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that any element you place as an immediate child in `#DockedPlayer` is displayed on one line, use the following wildcard child selector (parent followed by greater than symbol and a `*`):

```
#DockedPlayer > * {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/kgms5spc/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/kgms5spc/1/)

Alternatively, you can just ensure the current elements are displayed on one line by the following:

```
#DockedPlayer > text, #DockedPlayer > img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

EDIT: For responsiveness. Once the viewport hits a certain width, simply make the elements display as blocks:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #DockedPlayer > * {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kgms5spc/3/